# Regular expression to validate a string representing either number or addition of numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

Help on validation expression to validate a string representing either number or addition of numbers.

e.g:

```
2 OK
22 + 3 OK
2+3 not OK
2 +3 not OK
2 + 34 + 45 OK
2 + 33 + not OK
2 + 33+ 4 not OK
```

Comment: Why do you think a regular expression is the correct choice for such a thing?

Comment: @Oded I have a input field on an Asp.net page which should accept this pattern only. I wanted to validate this using a regular expression validator

Comment: Is more than one space between numbers and the plus operators OK or not? And why are spaces mandatory in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

This would be quite a simple pattern

```
^\d+(?: \+ \d+)*$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vlo8)

`^` anchor for the start of the string

`$` anchor for the end of the string

The anchors are needed, otherwise the pattern will match "partly"

`\d+` is at least one digit

`(?: \+ \d+)*` is a non capturing group that can be there 0 or more times (because of the `*` quantifier at the end)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/^\d+(\s+\+\s+\d+)*$/
```

This matches a number followed by an optional plus sign and number, which can then be repeated.